# Does windows support hard drives larger than 2tb?

Tags: windows-server-2003, hard-drive, raid5

I have 6 x 500Gb drives formatted in raid 5. I have installed Windows Server 2003 R2 on 20Gb of this and want to format the rest as a backup drive (2.2Tb) is this possible?

I have found the following http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/device/storage/LUN_SP1.mspx which I thought suggested it was possible with SP1 but now I am unsure. I know I have SP2 installed now and the disk management tools is showing my unallocated disk space in two chucks, 2027.97Gb and 278.25Gb, but I want to use both these chunks as one drives.

Is anyone able to explain how I can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to convert the logical disk to GPT. You can do this in disk management by right clicking on it and selecting "Convert to GPT." This will allow you to create a volume over 2TB.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do I need to convert the entire thing to GPT then repartition? If possible I would rather not have to do this but it is a fresh install so I won't lose any data if I do.

Comment: I believe you can convert without repartitioning, but I've never done it to a boot volume, so be careful. When working with volume that large, I've always have a small mirror for the OS and a large array for the rest.